# When using spacemacs, where do I put my init file?

Tags: spacemacs, init-file

I've installed Spacemacs on ubuntu.

I've got some functions that I'd like to bring over from my old (vanilla) Emacs configuration.

Where do I put them?

The convention for normal Emacs is that users functions and configurations can go in your init file, in `~/.emacs.d/`. But Spacemacs doesn't pick that up.

Where do I put my init file for Spacemacs?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, you can put the original functions and configs directly into `dotspacemacs/user-config` or `dotspacemacs/user-init` of `.spacemacs.d/init.el` or `.spacemacs`.

For better organization, you can write your own layers and put the functions under `.spacemacs.d/layers/[layer-name]/funcs.el`. Then add custom layers to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`. The layers directory also supports the files `config.el`, `keybindings.el`, `layers.el` and `packages.el`. You can refer to the [official layers](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/develop/layers) or [my previous configuration](https://github.com/tshu-w/spacemacs-configuration/tree/master/layers/editor).